# Collections.sort(List<T> t, Comparator<T> c) don't work

Tags: java, sorting, collections

I was trying to implement custom ordering of integer array. The logic is : find median and order by distance to it. The thing is that I tried to sort using Comparator , and was wondering why variant with List don't work, while the same Arrays.sort worked for me.

Please find code below, under comments are lines used for List variant.

```
public static Integer[] sort(Integer[] array) {
    //implement logic here
    if (array == null) return null;
    final Integer[] tempArray = Arrays.copyOf(array, array.length);
    Arrays.sort(tempArray);
    final int median = tempArray.length%2==1 ? tempArray[tempArray.length/2] : (tempArray[tempArray.length/2]+tempArray[tempArray.length/2 - 1])/2;



    //final List<Integer> t = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(array));
    final Integer[] t = tempArray;
    //Collections.sort(t, new Comparator<Integer>()
    Arrays.sort(t, new Comparator<Integer>()
    {
        @Override
        public int compare(Integer i1, Integer i2)
        {
            Integer one = Math.abs(i1 - median);
            Integer two = Math.abs(i2 - median);
            Integer var1 = one - two;
            Integer var2 = two - one;
            System.out.println(String.format("Compare:\r\nmedian: %d\r\narg1: %d , arg2: %d\r\n"+
                    "distance1: %d, distance2: %d\r\nif dist1 > dist2 then compare: %d, else %d", median, i1, i2,one,two, var2,var1));
            System.out.println(String.format("\r\nresult: %d %s %d",i1, (one >  two?"<":one < two?">":i1.compareTo(i2)>0?">":"<"), i2));
            System.out.println("\r\n\r\nNow array is: "+Arrays.asList(t));
            System.out.println("-------------------------------");

            if (one ==  two) {
                return i1.compareTo(i2);
            } else
                return one.compareTo(two);
        }
    });

    //tempArray = (Integer[]) t.toArray(new Integer[t.size()]);

    return t;
}``
```

Comment: What output do you have? What output do you want?

Comment: You are sorting `tempArray` twice but the list only once, since `tempArray` is a copy of `array` and not a reference and the list is created from `array` and not from `tempArray`. That might not your actual problem but it's a difference since the array `t` will already be presorted while the list won't.

Comment: @Tunaki   for input:{1,10,6,2,3,1,1} i expect output: [2, 1, 1, 1, 3, 6, 10] , but if I use List , {1,10,6,2,3,1,1}  still the same on each iteration of compare method

Comment: I roll it back. @Thomas thanks for the comment, I miss read it...

Comment: Try `new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(tempArray));` (or just `List<Integer> t = Arrays.asList(tempArray)`) to remove the difference.

Comment: @Thomas thanks, I tried all these variant before post this question, but it also makes no difference.

Comment: I can't see any difference then, the comparator should work for lists as it does for arrays. I also tested your code with lists and the input you provided in your comment and it works fine. So please carefully look at your version to spot any minor differences (e.g. sorting the wrong list, returning the wrong array, a semicolon where none should be etc.). Also step through your code with a debugger to see where it doesn't produce the results you expect and whether and when certain methods are called.

Answer (score 3):

your comparation of Integers is wrong...

```
if (one ==  two) {
```

must be replaced by

```
if (one.intValue() ==  two.intValue()) {
```

if not, you are comparing references and not the value of the integers...

Comment: Or just `one.equals(two)`.

Comment: thanks for correction. But still this code works for Array.sort and produce correct order. So , why it doesn't work for List...